# Xamarin Forms android speech recognition ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, activitynotfoundexception

I've been trying to add speech-to-text to my android app but i'm keep getting "Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundAcception". 
I'm using android 5.0 (lollipop) emulator since my computer can't start any other emulator.

Interface:

```c#
    public interface ISpeech
    {
        Task<string> SpeechToTextAsync();
    }
```

Creating intent and starting activity:

```c#
    // When i remove Java.Lang.Object it gives Java.Lang.NullPointer Exception 
    public class AndroidSpeech : Java.Lang.Object, ISpeech
    {
        public static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private Intent voiceIntent;
        public static readonly int speech = 10; // requestCode
        public static string speechResults;
        public async Task<string> SpeechToTextAsync()
        {
            var context = Forms.Context;
            var activity = (Activity)context;
            voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPrompt, "Speak");
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.Default);
            autoEvent.Reset();
            activity.StartActivityForResult(voiceIntent, speech);
            await Task.Run(() => { autoEvent.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3)); });
            return speechResults;
        }
    }
```

It works fine until getting OnActivityResult, here it throwes the exception 
Main Activity:

```c#
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == AndroidSpeech.speech)
    {
       // resultCode returns Result.Canceled
       if (resultCode == Result.Ok) // here it throws ActivityNotFoundException
       {
          var speech = data.GetStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraResults);
          AndroidSpeech.speechResults = speech[0];
       }
       AndroidSpeech.autoEvent.Set();
    }
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Calling function on button click:

```c#
 private async void OnStartBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
      string speechResults = await DependencyService.Get<ISpeech().SpeechToTextAsync();
      Lbl.Text = speechResults;
 }
```

I also tried:

```c#
    [Activity]
    public class AndroidSpeech : Activity, ISpeech
    {
        // this gives Java.Lang.NullPointer Exception 
    }
```

And i also tried creating my own RecognitionListener but i can't return the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the `"Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundAcception".` Because xamarin Dependencyservice just have on activity, and `AndroidSpeech` is not a activity, you do not use `StartActivityForResult` directly.Solution is to get a reference to the current activity, in order to do that we are going to add one nuget called `Plugin.Current activity`

You can add the activity callbacks in our Application class, so my application class looks like this

```
  [Application]
public class MainApplication : Application, Application.IActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer)
      : base(handle, transer)
    {
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
        //A great place to initialize Xamarin.Insights and Dependency Services!
    }

    public override void OnTerminate()
    {
        base.OnTerminate();
        UnregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    public void OnActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityPaused(Activity activity)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityResumed(Activity activity)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
    {
    }

    public void OnActivityStarted(Activity activity)
    {
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnActivityStopped(Activity activity)
    {
    }
}
```

And in AndroidSpeech class you get the reference to the current activity like this

`_activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;`

Then you can call `StartActivityForResult` in `AndroidSpeech`

There is Blog about how to achieved speech-to-text step by step, you could refer to it.
https://medium.com/@dev.aritradas/xamarin-forms-speech-recognition-c16f07cdf164

and this is demo.
https://github.com/dev-aritra/XFSpeech

**update**
This is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer( please click the “✔” at the right of answer). It will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Target of StartActivityForResult is null (NullReferenceException) i get this,
"CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity"  returns null.

Comment: Okay now i can start speech recognizer using "((Activity)Forms.Context)" but after speech ends speechResults returns null (it never calls "OnActivityResult").

Comment: I test this code in my pixel, code :https://github.com/851265601/SpeechToTextDemo. You should run this code in android device, not run it in your android emulator.

Comment: I tried your code with two different phones but still can't return speech results.

Comment: I update my running GIF, you could see that in answer, I updated it , that is worked, Do your phones meet these requirements?  1.Phones need install `google play service`,2.Connect to the network(it could access Google). You also could upload your code, i will test it for you in pixel to exclude problems of phones.

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.